# E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate on dockerfile execution

Tags: docker

I'm new on docker and I'm trying to run this dockerfile

```
 FROM php:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \ 
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends

RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /app
```

but I get this error

```
FROM php:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \ 
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends

RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

WORKDIR /app
```

what should I use instead of `mysql-client`?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is no `mysql-client` candidate to install

Answer (score 1):

You should try this image
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-containerize-a-laravel-6-application-for-development-with-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-18-04-es

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Update without triggering any scripts

RUN composer update --no-scripts  

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

Answer (score 1):

it is usually `mariadb-client` now, i think past PHP 7.1+ they changed the sql version for the base image